# Convert Gregorian (Christian) date to Persian date and vice-versa in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

How can I convert `Gregorian date` to `Persian date` and vice-versa in `Python`?

[All I found](https://github.com/behzadi/persianDatepicker) was some widgets and stuffs which will create Persian Calendar. I don't want a Persian calendar. I just want to convert dates to each other.
So how can I do that?

Answer (score 63):

Also, you can use `jdatetime` library like the following:

```
 import jdatetime
 gregorian_date = jdatetime.date(1396,2,30).togregorian()
 jalili_date =  jdatetime.date.fromgregorian(day=19,month=5,year=2017)
```

See other functions in details in [this document](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jdatetime).

Answer (score 18):

You can use [PersianTools](https://pypi.org/project/persiantools/) library:

Example:

```python
>>> from persiantools.jdatetime import JalaliDate
>>> import datetime

>>> JalaliDate.today()
JalaliDate(1395, 4, 18, Jomeh)

>>> JalaliDate(datetime.date(1990, 9, 23))  # Gregorian to Jalali
JalaliDate(1369, 7, 1, Yekshanbeh)

>>> JalaliDate.to_jalali(2013, 9, 16)       # Gregorian to Jalali
JalaliDate(1392, 6, 25, Doshanbeh)

>>> JalaliDate(1392, 6, 25).to_gregorian()  # Jalali to Gregorian
datetime.date(2013, 9, 16)

>>> JalaliDate.fromtimestamp(578707200)     # Timestamp to Jalali
JalaliDate(1367, 2, 14, Chaharshanbeh)
```

Answer (score 8):

## pip install jdatetime

```
import jdatetime 
fa_date = jdatetime.date.today()
fa_date.j_months_fa[0]
jdatetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")#'Tue, 05 Far 1399 15:49:44'
jdatetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y %m %d") #'99 01 05'
jdatetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y %m %d") # '1399 01 05'

jdatetime.datetime.now().strftime('%A %B')


 import jdatetime
 jalili_date = jdatetime.date(1399,1,5).togregorian()
 gregorian_date =  jdatetime.date.fromgregorian(day=24 ,month=3,year=2020)
```

Answer (score 6):

First you have to install the `jdatetime` with pip

```
pip install jdatetime
```

the library `Jdateimte` is so weak and non-friendly without any valid documentation, almost everyone get confused over it (thanks to it's Iranian development).
but here's the drill:

```
timestamp = 1647334174.7492166
jdatetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
#returns 'jdatetime.datetime(1400, 12, 24, 1, 48, 17, 532053)'
```

From your 'datetime' object:

```
yourDate = datetime.datetime.now()
jdatetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(inputDate.timestamp())
#returns same result as before.
```

Answer (score 3):

I didnt see khayyam package in the answers so here is the link:

https://pypi.org/project/Khayyam/

it is faster than jdatetime and better maintained

Answer (score 0):

**pip install jdatetime**

```
import jdatetime
gregorian_date = jdatetime.date(1400,5,24).togregorian()
jalili_date =  jdatetime.date.fromgregorian(day=1,month=12,year=2021)
```

Comment: Please help me see the difference to the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069366/7733418 The only difference I see is in the date numbers, the broken formatting, the lack of explanation. I.e. I see no contribution in your post and a few issues which make it less readable and less helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import jdatetime
jalili_date = jdatetime.datetime.fromgregorian(day=4, month=9, year=2022, hour=9, minute=0, second=0)
print(jalili_date)
```